# UnicodeDecodeError when using django serializers

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a custom django user model and a "Photo" model with Foreign Key as "CustomUser" model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = CustomUserManager()
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

and

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(blank=False, null=False, upload_to="images")
    author = models.ForeignKey('users.CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I am trying to get the 'profile_pic' field (defined in CustomUser) from Photo Serializer but i get an utf-8 error.
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DFjW.jpg)

Photo Serializer:

```
class PhotoSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    email = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_user_email')
    username = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_username')
    profile_pic = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_profile_pic')
    
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ['id', 'author','image', 'title','email', 'username', 'profile_pic']

    def get_user_email(self, photo):
        email = photo.author.email
        return email

    def get_username(self, photo):
        username = photo.author.username
        return username
        
    def get_profile_pic(self, photo):
        photo_url = photo.author.profile_pic  
        return photo_url
```

If I replace get_profile_pic with the following code below, it gives the correct image url. But is there any other way to do it? Also I would like to know the reason for the error.

```
def get_profile_pic(self, photo):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        photo_url = photo.author.profile_pic  
        photo_url = 'media/' + str(photo_url)
        return request.build_absolute_uri(photo_url)
```

Comment: Is it not `photo.author.profile_pic_url`? (missing `_url` suffix?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `get_profile_pic` returns an `ImageFieldFile` object instead of `str`.

You should use the `url` property:

```
def get_profile_pic(self, photo):
    photo_url = photo.author.profile_pic.url
    return photo_url
```

See [Using files in models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/files/#using-files-in-models)